# Socket.IO - Callback to user who emited only

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am making a chat application which requires users to log in, I have so far managed to get the login system working by using UserApp.io, but I cant seem to find a way which would send a "Callback" back to the user who has emited the information to the server.

So for **index.html**, when a login form is submitted, it would gather the values of the two fields and emit the data to the backend.

```
$('form#login').submit(function() {
    var data = {};

    data.email = $("#login_email").val();
    data.password = $("#login_password").val();

    socket.emit('user login', data);
});
```

In the **index.js** file, it receives the details and checks using the UserApp API that the user is valid and all the details are correct. It also retrieves information like the first and last name.

```
socket.on('user login', function (user) {
    logger.info('Receiving login info for "' + user.email + '"...');

    UserApp.User.login({"login": user.email, "password": user.password}, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            logger.error('Login failed: ' + error.message);
        } else {
            var userToken = result.token;
            var userID = result.user_id;
            console.log("User has logged in.");

            UserApp.User.get({
                "user_id": userID
            }, function (error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    logger.error(error.message);
                } else {
                    logger.info(result[0]['first_name'] + " " + result[0]['last_name'] + " Has logged in!")
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So here is my issue. I cant seem to find a way of giving a callback to index.html so it can show errors like "Incorrect username".

So is there a way of giving a callback to one person, more specificly, the person who submitted the login form?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.io has acknowledgement callbacks, here are the docs

http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements)

Add a callback function as the third argument when emitting

```
$('form#login').submit(function() {
    var data = {};

    data.email = $("#login_email").val();
    data.password = $("#login_password").val();

    socket.emit('user login', data, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

and then the callback function server side can have an additional parameter which is the callback you defined when emitting

```
socket.on('user login', function (user, callback) {
    logger.info('Receiving login info for "' + user.email + '"...');

    UserApp.User.login({"login": user.email, "password": user.password}, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            logger.error('Login failed: ' + error.message);
        } else {
            var userToken = result.token;
            var userID = result.user_id;
            console.log("User has logged in.");

            UserApp.User.get({
                "user_id": userID
            }, function (error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    logger.error(error.message);
                } else {
                    logger.info(result[0]['first_name'] + " " + result[0]['last_name'] + " Has logged in!")
                    return callback('your results');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes! That seems to have done the trick, thank you very much. This will come in handy for more than this.